# Regular expression for checking every substring

Tags: regex, finite-automata, deterministic

I had this question in my end semester exam, unfortunately I couldn't solve it and tried it for several days and no luck.

Condition- For every substring of length 4 in a string of length n, write a RE to force the rule- there must be exactly three 1's.

My solution kind of looked like 
(1+11+111+€)(0111)*(0+€).

But this is obviously wrong, string 11011 is a valid solution too.

Update- my new solution is (1+11+111+€)(0111)*(0+01+011+€).

Update- the plus operator is actually 'OR'

Update- € is empty string

Update -  the string length has no requirements. A string of length 5 will have 2 substrings of length 4, the first 4 chars and the last 4 chars

Comment: What happens if the string has 10 characters?  How do we handle the final two characters?

Comment: We can handle only 4 consecutive characters at a time, the last substring would be the last 4 characters

Comment: So we can assume the string is a multiple of 4 length then?

Comment: Nope, the string length has no requirements. A string of length 5 will have 2 substrings of length 4, the first 4 chars and the last 4 chars

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the repetition operator. `11+11+1` matches five or more 1s, where the second and the fourth may be repeated more than once. (This doesn't make any sense; because of greediness, the second will repeat as many times as possible, and the fourth will never get more than one.)

Comment: Ah, the plus operator is actually 'OR'

Comment: You might want to document the other oddities in your notation, too.  What's €?

Comment: Epsilon, empty string

Comment: There's a character for that, obviously.  [ε aka GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON (U+03B5)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3b5/index.htm).  Instead of plus I guess you mean [∪ aka UNION (U+222A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/222a/index.htm)

Comment: I'll change it once I get on my computer

Answer (score 0):

I think the professor is looking for the realization that in order for the condition to hold, a 1 may never be bracketed by zeros on both sides.

```
(0?11)*
```

To complete the picture, we also need to include the case for *n*=1 where either a 0 or a 1 is allowed (I presume).

```
^[01]$|(0?11)*
```

I'm using traditional regex here, where `[...]` denotes a character class, `|` is "or", parentheses do grouping, and `*` specifies zero or more repetitions (Kleene star).

Comment: Wouldn't 011011 be in your RE language? But consider the first substring of length 4, 0110 - it has two 1's but we need exactly three 1's.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the "exactly" and assumed "at least".  Do you want me to delete this answer or should I leave it as a clue for someone else to perhaps develop to a working answer?

Comment: It's okay, you can leave it here. If you get the answer, post it here !

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Consider the following regular expression where **€** refers to the empty string and assuming the alphabet consists of only **{0,1,€}**:

€ + (0111)* + (1110)* + (1101)* + (1011)*

Comment: 01110 is not in your RE but 01110 is a valid string

Answer (score 0):

Python 2

```
import re

# regular expression
# '^' in the start of the expression means from the very start of the string
# "[^1.]*" means match any character unless it is '1'
# '$' in the end of the expression means till the very end of the string
# Summary:
# from the start of the string till the end of it check if we have
# '1' exactly 3 times, 
# and before or after them you might find any type of characters
# and these characters must not be equal '1' ...
expression = '^[^1.]*1[^1.]*1[^1.]*1[^1.]*$'

# testing strings
tests = ["01110", "11100", "00111", "010101", "00100100111", "00100"]


prog = re.compile(expression)

for test in tests:
    print 'matched' if prog.match(test) else 'not matched'
```

Comment: could you explain how you came up with this ?

Comment: I have updated my answer adding more explanation on how the regular expression works, this is a link that may help you figure out how regular expressions work http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html